# divide column from one table to column from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've two tables

```
    TB_1                      TB_3

Month     Total         Month        Total
2012-01     6          2012-01         12
2013-02     6          2013-02         12
2014-03     10         2014-03         20
2015-04     10         2015-04         20
```

In result table I need follow result:

```
      RESULT_TB

Month        Total
2012-01       2
2013-02       2
2014-03       2
2015-04       2
```

I tried the following:

```
Select TB_3.total / TB_1.total 
From TB_3, TB_1
```

But it does not work, tell me please, how to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select t1.month,
    case 
        when t1.total = 0
            then null
        else t2.total / t1.total
        end total
from tb_1 t1
join tb_3 t2 on t1.month = t2.month
```

I used `CASE` to ensure if there is zero total in tb_1 table, the output comes as `NULL` instead of throwing a *divide by zero* error.

Comment: Thank you @GurV!  And if I want to consider how many percent number 2 from number 6 makes? It can be done?

Comment: @Kirill - How do you mean? Please ask a new question with details of what you want to get.

Answer (score 0):

You only seem to need a proper `JOIN` condition:

```
Select t3.month, t3.total / t1.total 
From TB_3 t3 JOIN
     TB_1 t1
     ON t3.month = t1.month;
```

Note:  If the tables have different sets of months, then you might want some sort of outer join.

Also, Postgres does integer division when both operands are integers.  It is unclear whether you want that or not.  But if the values were "15" and "2", then the result would be "7" rather than "7.5".

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
     SELECT ISNULL(T1.Month,T2.Month) AS Month
          , CASE WHEN ISNULL(T1.Total,0) = 0 THEN ISNULL(T2.Total,0)
                 ELSE ISNULL(T2.Total,0)/ISNULL(T1.Total,0)
              END AS Total
       FROM TB_1 AS T1
  FULL JOIN TB_2 AS T2 ON T1.Month = T2.Month
```

I have used **FULL JOIN** to catch all dates from both tables. I have checked for all NULL values and replaced the NULLs by divisible values.

Answer (score 0):

For matching months only, use this -

```
select    TB_1.month                        as month
         ,TB_3.total / nullif(TB_1.total,0) as total

from            TB_1 
          join  TB_3 
          on    TB_3.month = TB_1.month

order by  month
```

If you wish to also display results for nonmatching months, use this -

```
select    coalesce(TB_1.month,TB_3.month)     as month
         ,TB_3.total / nullif(TB_1.total,0)   as total

from                  TB_1 
          full join   TB_3 
          on          TB_3.month = TB_1.month

order by  month
```

1. `nullif(X,0)` is a clean way to express-
   Return `X` unless it is equal to `0`, where in that case return a `NULL`
2. If the `total` column are of integer type, replace `TB_3.total` with `TB_3.total::numeric(12,2)` (or other precision as you like)