# Calculating ratio between two similar table columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have this table

```
Code1   Month1   Month2   Month3 
--------------------------------
Delta    2000     3000     1000
Charlie  1000     1000     2000
Bravo     800      200      300
```

and I have another similar temp table with data from a different calculation aspect

```
Code1     Month1  Month2  Month3 
--------------------------------
Delta      1000    3000   3000
Charlie     300     400    200
Bravo       400     200    300
```

I was wondering how I can merge data from both tables into one with it being in the following format

```
Code1      Month1  Month2  Month3 
---------------------------------
Delta   2      ........
Charlie 3.3    ...
Bravo   2      ....
```

Which is basically matching the rows and then doing 1st table column / 2nd table column.

A rough approach I have is to just join the table into one big table using and then creating another temp table by dividing the joined columns but was wondering if there is a better approach.

Thanks

Comment: Do you just want to select the data like that, or do you want a whole new table like that? A view?

Comment: Assuming that `Code1` is unique in each table, `JOIN` seems like the right approach.

Comment: I just want to select the data and return the data from the stored proc..Looks like this thread covers what I want https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42189578/divide-column-from-one-table-to-column-from-another-table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I came up with based on this link [divide column from one table to column from another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42189578/divide-column-from-one-table-to-column-from-another-table)

```
SELECT ISNULL(T1.Code,T2.Code) AS Code
          , CASE WHEN ISNULL(T1.Month1,0) = 0 THEN ISNULL(T2.Month1,0)
                 ELSE ISNULL(T2.Month1,0)/ISNULL(T1.Month1,0)
              END AS Month1,
              CASE WHEN ISNULL(T1.Month2,0) = 0 THEN ISNULL(T2.Month2,0)
                 ELSE ISNULL(T2.Month2,0)/ISNULL(T1.Month2,0)
              END AS Month2,
              CASE WHEN ISNULL(T1.Month3,0) = 0 THEN ISNULL(T2.Month3,0)
                 ELSE ISNULL(T2.Month3,0)/ISNULL(T1.Month3,0)
              END AS Month3
       FROM #TempBidCost AS T1
  FULL JOIN #TempBidRevenue AS T2 ON T1.Code = T2.Code
```

Comment: from the sample data, It seems that there is no need for full outer join (such complication). If the data is 1 to 1 it is better to use inner join for performance consideration

Comment: I also suggest you look up the difference between `ISNULL()` and `is null` the second would suit your query much better.

Comment: `/ISNULL(T1.Month1,0)` etc. -- That could cause a division by zero.

Answer (score 1):

you can use inner join

```
select 
  t1.Code1, 
  (t1.month1 * 1.0) / t2.month1 as month1,
  (t1.month2 * 1.0) / t2.month2 as month2,
  (t1.month3 * 1.0) / t2.month3 as month3
from t1
inner join t2 on t1.code1 = t2.code1
```

**Please note that:**

From the provided sample data, It seems that there is no need for full outer join. If the data is 1 to 1 it is better to use inner join for performance consideration

Answer (score 1):

If you have all matching rows, then `inner join` is fine.  I wouldn't really recommend `full outer join` if you care about the non-matches.  Instead, `union all` provides an approach:

```
select code1,
       sum(month1) / nullif(sum(month1_2), 0) as ratio_1,
       sum(month2) / nullif(sum(month2_2), 0) as ratio_1,
       sum(month3) / nullif(sum(month3_2), 0) as ratio_1,
from ((select t1.code1, month1, month2, month3
       from t1
      ) union all
      (select t2.code1, null, null, null, t2.month1 as month1_2, t2.month2 as month2_2, t2.month3 as month3_2
       from t2
      )
     ) t
group by code1;
```

Answer (score 0):

UNION merges rows, so this is what you need to stake one table on top of another but joins stacks columns nexts to each other

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Table2
```